# The graph output of an xml format and the output of Mathematica

Tags: graphics, xml

Based on below command:

```
  Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4,
 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 3 \[UndirectedEdge] 6,
  4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {1, 
    2}, {2, 2}}]
```

we can draw a graph as 
[image]

Mathematica does its job feasibly. However for input of several programs we have to use a file with xml format. For instants, the above created graph via commands defined in xml format have to be written as below which is encapsulated in ah "file.xml".

```
 </LATTICES>

<LATTICE name="sqd" dimension="2">
  <PARAMETER name="a" default="1"/>
  <BASIS>
     <VECTOR>a 0</VECTOR>
     <VECTOR>0 a</VECTOR>
 </BASIS>
</LATTICE>


<UNITCELL name="unicross" dimension="2">
  <VERTEX id="1" ><COORDINATE> 0   0 </COORDINATE></VERTEX>
  <VERTEX id="2" ><COORDINATE> 0   1 </COORDINATE></VERTEX>
  <EDGE ><SOURCE vertex="1"/><TARGET vertex="2"/></EDGE>
  <EDGE ><SOURCE vertex="1"/><TARGET vertex="1" offset="1 0"/></EDGE>
  <EDGE ><SOURCE vertex="2"/><TARGET vertex="2" offset="1 0"/></EDGE>
  <EDGE ><SOURCE vertex="1"/><TARGET vertex="2" offset="1 0"/></EDGE>
  <EDGE ><SOURCE vertex="2"/><TARGET vertex="1" offset="1 0"/></EDGE>
</UNITCELL>

<LATTICEGRAPH name = "sqdcross" >
 <FINITELATTICE>
   <LATTICE ref="sqd"/>
   <PARAMETER name="W" default="1"/>
   <PARAMETER name="L" default="2"/>
   <EXTENT dimension="1" size="L"/>
   <EXTENT dimension="2" size="W"/>
   <BOUNDARY dimension="1" type="periodic"/>
   <BOUNDARY dimension="2" type="open"/>
  </FINITELATTICE>
 <UNITCELL ref="unicross"/>
</LATTICEGRAPH>

</LATTICES>
```

In the unitcell, two vertices is defined at coordinate `{0,0} and {0,1}`. With `W=1` this unitcell is not repeated in the vertical direction and with `L=2` it is allowed to grow horizontally to construct another cell. Albeit with periodic condition in this direction we have two additional vertices at the end of the graph. In the part of unitcell we defined the vertices and edges as we expected from the graph.

**Although I do not know how to draw the graph nexus to the xml file**.
In fact, how can I check the output of the xml graph is according to what was extracted from Mathematica?

Comment: considered [GraphML](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/GraphML.html) or [GXL](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/GXL.html)?

Comment: I'm sorry but your 'Graph' will not be shown because of a seventh Vertex which isn't used. And the VertexCoordinates do not create your graph picture.